# How to create a regular expression to find a substring within a larger string?

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string, e.g.: "Consensus IRIS 2010-11 Series 6"

If someone types part of that string, e.g. "iris" into a textbox, how can I identify the substring in the original string?

I have the following, but it only matches when the string *starts* with the value from the text box.

```
var txt= $('#txtName').val();

var regExp = new RegExp("^" + txt, "i");

var t = item.name.replace(regExp, "<span class='matched-text'>" + txt + "</span>");
```

Side note: I am baffled by regular expressions!

Comment: Good resource for regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var regExp = new RegExp(txt, "i");
```

Or this:

```
var regExp = new RegExp("\b"+txt"\b", "i");
```

The first will match `txt` anywhere in the string, even in the middle of a word. The second will not match in the middle of a word.

Answer (score 2):

Because your regular expression begins with `^` it will only match sequences that begin with whatever the value of `txt` is. Remove the `^` and you're set.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from the fact that prepending `"^"` to your regular expression makes it only match at the beginning of the string/text box. Remove that and it should work as expected for normal substrings.

However, if someone types a regular expression into the search box, your code could have unexpected effects. For example, if someone typed in `\w`, every letter and number would be highlighted. [This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is good for learning more about regular expressions.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that special characters have to be escaped.